# not able to modify this pointer

Tags: c++

why I am not able to modify this pointer? getting compilation error "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment".
Following is the program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
public:
  Test(int x = 0) { this->x = x; }
  void change(Test *t) { this = t; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj(5);
  Test *ptr = new Test (10);
  obj.change(ptr);
  obj.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you can't; `this` isn't an lvalue. What are you hoping to accomplish by doing it?

Comment: but "this" is not a constant pointer?

Comment: You can change value of the members (`this->x = t->x`) but not pointer to the object itself.

Comment: It does not make sense. This is the pointer to the object you are dealing with, changing it would be like 'i'm fed with this object, I'll pass to another one'.

Comment: ok , got it , this is part of standard , but is there any reasoning behind it? why cant we change value of this pointer?

Comment: @pankajkushwaha It would just not make any sense. `this` *always* holds the address of the current object. You cannot change said address. Thus, you cannot change `this`.

Comment: ok...thanks to all you guys for clarification...

Comment: note that you can do this: `*this = other_obj`

Comment: Which in his code would be `*this = *t;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign to `this`, you should think of it as conceptually constant pointer `Test *const this`.

What you actually need to do in `change()` is just copy the contents of `t`:

```
void change(Test *t) {this->x = t->x;}
```

If you want to be a good C++ citizen you could also make `t` constant:

```
void change(const Test *t) {this->x = t->x;}
```